# Xamarin.Forms disable Shell TabBar font scale when selected

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-bottomnav, xamarin.forms.shell

Is there any way to disable behavior of tab bar scaling font size for selected items on Android?
It cuts off titles when selected which is very annoying.
I could not find TabBar renderer kind of thing to change behavior on Android side.

[image]

The last item 'Notificaitons' are being cut to 'Notificatio' when it is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `dimens.xml` in Android> Resource> values. And then add the following XML to override the size of the text when it is active and not active:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]